# Why am I NOT able to upload files with the following NodeJS code?

Tags: node.js, express, multer-gridfs-storage

I am trying to design a simple app in NodeJS that uploads a CSV file via an HTML form.
Having carefully followed this tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVOFt8Its6I) on how to upload files using NodeJS, I don't understand why my code isn't able to upload any file. I haven't gotten further than 6:53 mins in the youtube tutorial.

Find below my simple code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');    

const fileStorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cd)=> {
    cd(null, './uploads')   
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null, Date.now() + '--' + file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({storage: 'fileStorageEngine'});

app.get('/', (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(__dirname +'/testDir/form.html' );
});

app.post('/uploads', upload.single('file'), (req, res)=> {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send('Single File Upload Success!');
});
    
app.listen('3600', ()=> console.log('App is listening...'));
```

...and my HTML form code looks like this:
[image]

`http://localhost:3600/` correctly displays

[image]

I am able to browse to whatever file I choose, and clicking on the submit button that gets me directed to:

[image]

According to the [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVOFt8Its6I) at 6:53 mins, the **uploads** folder should now contain the uploaded file,
however, the folder is empty!

Also, the terminal displays

[image]

...suggesting that `console.log(req.file);` no file was actually read in.

I also tried using **postman** and this is a screenshot of the result:

[image]
I have tried to re-watching the video and carefully followed the instructions but still haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Kindly help me understand why the upload isn't working and how to resolve this issue.
Looking forward to your help.

Comment: the problem likely involves your client side javascript/html on `form.html`...can you edit your question to include that? At the very least it would be helpful to see your `form` tag and any javascript events associated with the form submission (e.g. submit button click events, form submit events, etc)

Comment: @David784 Oh sorry! I meant to post this too, but it slipped my mind. 
So as you can see there aren't any client-side javascript events linked to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `storage` field as a `string` instead of a `multer.diskStorage` object.

Change it to: `const upload = multer({storage: fileStorageEngine});`

Also make sure that the `key` value in Postman form-data is set to `file`, because you are using `upload.single('file')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! 
As you advised, I changed to 'const upload = multer({storage: fileStorageEngine});' but still not working. Also in postman, after clicking send, I get: Can not POST/

Comment: In your `form.html` file, the `input` tag with type `file` must have the id (and name) as "file", because that's what you have passed in `upload.single()`. Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-butterfly-9f6xp?file=/app.js) for your reference. Also, in Postman, your POST request must be sent to "localhost:3600/uploads".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form. Also, make sure you have set name correctly. Can you paste the code for your form as well?

Comment: Sorry it slipped my mind to post the html form. However the enctype was already set to the correct type: 'enctype="multipart/form-data" '